# How to deal with &amp; in scala templates

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework

I am working with a simple CRUD web application that just stores some text entered by users in a MYSQL database. Using Play/Scala.

When a person enters a text like:

`"Hello & Good Riddance"`

The `"&"` sign changes to `"&amp;"` when stored in the mysql database.

So when I retrieve back the text and display it, its shown like:

`"Hello &amp; Good Riddance"`

So, can anything be done to fix this issue, I have no problem with `"&"` -> `"&amp;"`when getting stored in DB, just want to display plain "&" when displaying the text in the webpage.

For e.g. Stackoverflow, automatically changes the "`&amp;"` to `"&"`, if I don't specify it as code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape it in their view so use ie.

```
@Html(myWelcomeText)
```

Instead of

```
@myWelcomeText
```